# Missing \endcsname inserted in table

Tags: tables

### MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twocolumn]{report}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

%\usepackage{verbatim}  
\begin{document}

\onecolumn

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
\multirow{6}{*}{\includegraphics[scale=.3]{example-image-a}} & \Large{ONE}     & \multirow{6}{*}{\includegraphics[scale=.3]{example-image-b}}\\
 & \Large{TWO} &\\
 & \Large{THREE} &\\
 & &\\
 & \Large{FOUR} &\\
 & \Large{FIVE} &\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

It takes `Missing \endcsname inserted` error. And in `.log` file,

> ! Missing \endcsname inserted.  
>                      \relax  l.20 ...ncludegraphics[scale=.3]{example-image-a}}
>                                                      & \Large{ONE} & \multirow...
>
> ?  ! Emergency stop.  
>                      \relax  l.20 ...ncludegraphics[scale=.3]{example-image-a}}
>                                                      & \Large{ONE} & \multirow... End of file on the terminal!

What will I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

turkish babel redefines `=` but you can locally turn this off:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twocolumn]{report}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

%\usepackage{verbatim}  
\begin{document}

\onecolumn

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}\shorthandoff{=}
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
\multirow{6}{*}{\includegraphics[scale=.3]{example-image-a}} & 
\Large ONE     & 
\multirow{6}{*}{\includegraphics[scale=.3]{example-image-b}}\\
 & \Large TWO &\\
 & \Large THREE &\\
 & &\\
 & \Large FOUR &\\
 & \Large FIVE &\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ow, did you discovered this now or you had already known it?

Comment: @Sigur both:-) I just discovered it, but I knew it before

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, Perfect working. [CLOSED]