# typesetting error in the `edtabular` environment of `reledmac` (missing \endcsname inserted) in conjunctin with babel greek

Tags: tables, babel, greek, reledmac

Currently I'm using the tabular environment of `reledmac` package and get the error message `missing \endcsname inserted`.

I think it's a similar problem like in this thread:
[Missing \endcsname inserted in table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229041/missing-endcsname-inserted-in-table)

Unless this time it's not the selection of turkish in the `babel` package but the polutonikogreek. But I can't solve it yet. Has anyone an idea what might it be? Thanks in advance for your help?

Here an MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage[ngerman,polutonikogreek]{babel}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}


\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\begin{edtabularc}%{c c|c c}
4&3&\edrowfill{3}{4}{\hrulefill}&\\
3&2&9&8.
\end{edtabularc}
\pend
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try without the Greek to figure out if that's the problem?!

Comment: Definitely the Greek. Not the shorthand, though. It would help if you could minimise your example.

Comment: Thanks for trying. Without the greek package loading it's working. I've reduced the MWE by removing the parallel pages environment. How could I figure it out what's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is clearly a reledmac bug.

I have corrected it in development branch.

Please download https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/archive/2.4.1-2.5.1.zip, run the .ins file to obtain the .sty file, put them along you .tex file and make feedback.

Comment: Fantastic! The pdf output is perfect with this version! Thanks a lot for fixing it that fast.

Comment: your welcome. Should be published next week on CTAN.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again. I still encountered an error when using this code: \begin{edtabularr}
\edvertline{2pc}&117
\end{edtabularr} It seems that the "&1" is interpreted as something other than it should be. The MWE is the same as above.

Comment: please open github issue for bug.